# JSON sending data through form

Tags: php, json, uploadify

I bought the uploadifive script and want to change some things.
I've added a textfield called "name" and a textfield called "about".

The basic script that comes with Uploadifive is:

the form:

```
    <form action="<?php echo $domein.'/uploadstap2.php'; ?>" method="post" name="THEFORM">
    <input name="naam" type="text">
    <div id="queue"></div>
    <input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" type="file" multiple>
    <a style="position: relative; top: 8px;" href="javascript:$('#file_upload').uploadifive('upload')">Upload Files</a>
</form>
```

The script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php $timestamp = time();?>
    $(function() {
        $('#file_upload').uploadifive({
            'auto'             : false,
            'checkScript'      : 'check-exists.php',
            'queueID'          : 'queue',
            'uploadScript'     : 'uploadifive.php',
            'onUploadComplete' : function(file, data) { console.log(data); }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The creaters wrote the following on there webppage:

> A JSON object containing additional data to send to the server-side upload script. 
>   Data sent via this option will be sent via the headers and can be accessed via the $_POST array (if using the ‘post’ method). So if you send something like {‘someKey’ : ‘someValue’}, then you can access it as $_POST['someKey'].

Dus, ik kan dit doen:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php $timestamp = time();?>
    $(function() {
        $('#file_upload').uploadifive({
            'auto'             : false,
            'checkScript'      : 'check-exists.php',
            'formData'         : {'someKey' : 'someValue'},   !!!!!!! <<<< this is what i just added >>>>!!!!!
            'queueID'          : 'queue',
            'uploadScript'     : 'uploadifive.php',
            'onUploadComplete' : function(file, data) { console.log(data); }
        });
    });
</script>
```

But i need the value that people enter in "name" and "about"  to be send on uploadComplete.
How can i send this values in stead of: {'someKey' : 'someValue'}

Can somebody help me?

Comment: { 'someKey' : 'someValue' } is a JSON format, but doesn't hold the variable because you need to define var first before using any value you want; then it'll let you to use val() binding to 'someValue'.

Comment: Yes, but i don't know how to get the value people add to the form in "someValue".

If i add a text in form "name", how can i send it to "uploadifive.php" when people click on "upload files" ??

Comment: just posted an example as an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `$('input[name=something]').val()` (where something is the name of your input) to get the value of the textbox by checking the name of the element. 
You can use like this for your example

`'formData'         :{name:$('input[name=name]').val(),about:$('input[name=about]').val()}`

Comment: Thank you, i changed it a little bit and now it works, did it this way:

    'formData'         : {           'naam'      : $('input[name=naam]').val()
                         },

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML Form:

```
   <form>
   <input type="input" id="firstname"> First name </input>
   <button>Submit</button>
   </form>
```

---

Inside your jquery wrapper (or javascript file) and this would pass the variable throughout.

```
   var someValue = $("#firstname").val();

   $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: './aProcessorScript.php',
       data: JSON.stringify ({'someKey' : 'someValue'}),
       success: function(data) { alert('data: ' + data); },
       dataType: 'json'
   });
```